# Fixing two uiviews size based on screen width & height in storyboard IOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, storyboard, constraints

Please tell me: how to do the below logic in **storyboard** using constraints.

**Fixing two UIViews(minimum :130x80) in screen. The center gap between uiviews always 20px.**

---

**screen:**

> 20px  **View1**       20px     **View2**     20px

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add the Leading Space Constraint between view1 and the screen : 20px

Add the Trainling Space Constraint between view2 and the screen : 20px

Add the Horizontal Spacing between the views : 20px

Add the Equal Widths between the two views.

And to not have errors, add the top + bottom constraints, or the Vertical center + Height on view1

Finish by adding the Same Top + Same Bottom constrains on view2.

Enjoy ;)

EDIT : 
Huh, I forgot that your views have Width >= 130.

Then, 130 + 130 + 20*3 = 320, which is the width of the screen on iPhones <= 5S.

And when you use the leading/trailing space constraints, iOS will start to count from 16px, then Leading Space 20 will give you X = 36, then you'll miss some place.

The solution is to set X = 20, and then pin the Leading space, or modify Leading Space value from 20 to 20 - 16 = 4. Same thing for the Trailing Space of the View2

Comment: I followed your steps. but it will works in iphone 6 (8.x) only. not works in 7.1.

Comment: anything to do more for ios 7? can you tell me.

Comment: Huh, I forgot that your views have Width >= 130. Then, 130 + 130 + 20*3 = 320, which is the width of the screen on iPhones <= 5S.
And when you use the leading/trailing space constraints,  iOS will start to count from 16px, then Leading Space 20 will give you X = 36, then you'll miss some place. 
The solution is to set X = 20, and then pin the Leading space, or modify Leading Space value from 20 to 20 - 16 = 4. Same thing for the Trailing Space of the View2